# integrate $\sqrt{1^2 + 4t^2 + 9t^4 }$

Tags: integration, substitution

I'm trying to compute the length of a curve.

I'm left with the definite integral 
$$
    \int \sqrt{1^2 + 4t^2 + 9t^4 }dt
$$
which i reduced to 
$$
    \int 2t\sqrt{1+(3 t/2)^2}dt
$$

I have a feeling I'm supposed to replace 3/2 t with -sint but I'm not completely sure. if i made it negative it would just square the negative...

but I'm stuck here.. I'm probably supposed to use a rule from calc 2 i forgot like u substitution but I can't remember how.. I've been looking up examples but I can't seem to apply it to here..

So how do I proceed to take this integral?

Comment: the first one .

Comment: Is the integral now the way you intend it? If not, I think it's better if you edit it yourself.

Comment: yes that's it..

Comment: You're missing a $\frac{1}{4t^2}$ inside the second $\sqrt{}$

Comment: Your first integral is an elliptic integral. The second is an elementary integral (which can be done by trig substitution). I don't believe the first reduces to the second.

Comment: can you show me how to take the square root of the elliptic integral?

Comment: i see that i set up my problem wrong. i saw an example of how to do it correctly in the book. thanks though.

Comment: come on guys this is not nearly bad enough for closing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have manipulated the first equation correctly,

$$\int 2t \sqrt{1+(\frac{3t}{2})^2}dt$$

$$t=\frac{2}{3}\tan x$$
$$dt=\frac{2}{3}\sec ^2xdx$$
$$\int \frac{4}{3}\tan x \sqrt{1+\tan^2 x} *\frac{2}{3}\sec ^2x dx$$
$$\frac{8}{9}\int \tan x \sec^3 x dx$$
$$\frac{8}{27}(\sec^3 x) +C$$

Then substitute $t$ back into the equation by writing $x$ in terms of $t$

$$\frac{9}{4} t^2=\tan^2x=\sec^2x-1$$
$$\sec^2x=\frac{9}{4}t^2+1$$

So the solution of the integral is

$$\frac{8}{27}(\frac{9}{4}t^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} +C$$

However, as pointed out by user222031, you have manipulated the first equation incorrectly.

Comment: i see that i set up my problem wrong. i saw an example of how to do it correctly in the book. thanks though.

Comment: "Assuming you have manipulated the first equation correctly" ...Which is not the case. Thus, why post this answer at all? The site is not in want of sensible questions, why not choose to answer **these** instead?

Comment: Sorry, Did, I usually start my answers with that because that was where the actual question began, where the asker was "stuck".  It is to make sure I do not write the wrong thing. It was only later that I noticed the first part did not lead to it, so I put it down. Which questions are you referring to?